# Transforming the form of trigonometric functions to the form $R\sin(\theta+\phi)$.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm just wondering how I would transform trigonometric functions with two negatives like:
$-A\sin(\theta)-B\cos(\theta)$

I'm well aware of the $R-\alpha$ rule and using it to find the value of $R$ and $\phi$.

For example:

$1\sin(\theta)+1\cos(\theta)$

$R=
\sqrt{1^2+1^2}\approx 1.41$

$\phi=\tan^{-1}(1/1)\approx 0.79$ rad.

$\text{Answer} = 1.41\sin(\theta+0.79)$

I struggle when there are two negatives in the question or a negative at all. I don't really understand what to do. Any help would be appreciated

I have a feeling I'm going wrong with the rule that $\phi$ should be: $−\pi\leq\phi<\pi$.

Comment: Have you tried doing this for $A \sin ( \phi) + B \cos (\phi)$ and then taking care of the minus sign?

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately my answer is wrong.

Comment: If we're working with the formula, $asin(x) + bcos(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}sin(x + tan^{-1}(a/b))$, I think it should work for negatives - For instance, if you had $-asin(x) - bcos(x)$, you'd just substitute -a and -b for a and b in formula, and if you have $asin(x) - bcos(x)$, you'd just substitute -b for b and a for a.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a, b > 0$. $R$-formula said $a \sin \alpha - b \cos \alpha = R \cos (\alpha + \phi)$
with $R$ and $\phi$ given respectlivly. Expression:
$- a \sin \alpha - b \cos \alpha $
is equal
$a \sin (-\alpha) - b \cos (-\alpha) $
because sinus is odd and cosine is even. So from $R$-formula we have:
$a \sin (-\alpha) - b \cos (-\alpha) = R \cos (-\alpha + \phi) = R\cos (\alpha -\phi) $.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $R=\sqrt {A^2+B^2}$ will always be positive, but to determine the angle $\phi$, you will have to determine in what quadrants where $\phi = \arctan \dfrac {B}{A}$ are positive and negative.

Since $A$ and $B$ are both negative, $\arctan \dfrac {B}{A}$ will be positive, but in which quadrant?  And how would you determine the angle in this case?